# how to remove first occurrence of 0 in mm/dd a date using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to remove first occurrence of 0 in mm/dd, e.g. I want to make `09/09/15` look like `9/9/15`.

I have tried using `echo 09/10/15 | sed 's/^.//'` but it gives output like `9/09/15`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Removing the 1st occurrence would give `9/09/15`. Did you mean all leading 0s?

Comment: I say "boo" to your date format. Use the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 01/01/2005 | sed 's=\(^\|/\)0=\1=g'
```

If 0 is preceded by the beginning of line or /, replace it with that (i.e. nothing or /).

Comment: what if it is preceded by a space?

Comment: @mikeserv: Such a case doesn't appear in the specification :-) But you can easily replace / with non-digit.

Comment: Good point. It's probably worth mentioning the `sed` versions this depends on. `sed -E 's=(^|[^0-9])0=\1=g'` would work with dashes or spaces or whatever in GNU `sed`. I think it also works with BSD `sed`, but I can't remember how that one handles `(^)` anchors in groups...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove all leading `0`s from the date string. If so, try this:

```
sed 's/0\([1-9]\)/\1/g'
```

That matches a `0` followed by any number from 1 to 9, and the parentheses capture that number. The entire pattern is then replaced with the >0 number matched (`\1`).

Comment: That  changes `2005` into `205`.

Comment: @mikeserv yes, but the OP specified a `dd/mm/yy` format.

Comment: ...I read mm/dd...

Comment: @mikeserv um, yes. That's what I meant. Point is, the OP specified only two characters per item.

Comment: Use `sed -e 's/^/#/' -e 's/\([^0-9]\)00*\([1-9][0-9]*\)/\1\2/g' -e 's/^\#//'` and the solution becomes generalised. Or where available `sed -r 's/\<0+([0-9]+)/\1/g'`

Comment: Including the delimiter will leave the year alone: `sed -r 's,0([[:digit:]]/),\1,g'`

Comment: @glennjackman true. I was assuming the OP also wanted to strip leading 0s from the year.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed 's/^/ /;s/\([^0-9.]\)0*\([1-9]\)/\1\2/g;s/.//' <infile >outfile
```

...will remove all leading zeroes from all numeric groups of characters which contain at least one non-zero digit on a line.